# Hide an entity with hook_entity_view_alter()

Tags: entities

I need to remove an entity from the display.

With `hook_entity_view_alter()`, I am trying to change the `$build` array.

```
$build['disable'] = true;
$build['#entity']['disable'] = true;
$build['#entity'] = "";
$build['#entity']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

This is all wrong.

$build['entity'] is of type Drupal\eck\Entity\EckEntity and not a renderarray.

What is the correct way to hide an entity from the display?

Comment: `$build['entity']['#access'] = FALSE;`?

Comment: $build['entity'] is of type Drupal\eck\Entity\EckEntity and no renderarray.
$build['#access'] = FALSE; also does not work.

Comment: Which entity is displayed doesn't change the code to use. @Clive code is correct. If you have any reason for not using it, please update your question to explain that.

Comment: `#access` to false.

Comment: @Clive I updated the question. 
['#entity'] is an object and not a render array. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Thank you - $build['#access'] = FALSE;  is working.