# Suitable way to hide a paragraph entity

Tags: 8, entities

I have read [Hide an entity with hook_entity_view_alter()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247405/hide-an-entity-with-hook-entity-view-alter), and by all rights this code should hide every paragraph on a page:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_paragraph_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $build['#access'] = false;
}
```

There are no errors, I know the function is being called because the debugger stops there on a breakpoint, I've cleared cache with every test.

I've tried `hook_entity_view`, `hook_entity_view_alter`, `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view` and `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter`.

None of them have any effect whether I'm logged in or not.

`['#access']` is not showing up in the build array in any of these hooks which makes me think the advice might be out of date since 8.4 dropped? If it does work - why should it work?

Are there any other ways, better ways of hiding paragraph entities (or any entity really)?

Obviously there will be some logic involved later which is why I want to do it in one of these hooks (or similar).

---

Edit 1: It has been suggested that there should be a $build['content'] array or similar. There is only the entity object in whichever hook I try of the four I have listed:

[image: inspect build variable]

Comment: Inspect the `$build` variable. Are you sure it shouldn't be something like `$build['content']['#access'] = false`?

Comment: I'd try try adding that #access property everywhere until something sticks. Maybe to #paragraph? Maybe the each field separately? If all else fails you could always try unsetting stuff?

Comment: Hehehe, yeah... that's why I'm here, I tried that already =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$build['#printed'] = TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`$build['#printed'] = TRUE` works but is heavily cached..you can set your cache though or still try
`$build['body']['0']['#access'] = FALSE;` OR

`$build['filter_this_view']['actions']['submit']['#access'] = FALSE;`

depending on your $build array structure. The fields will not be cached

Answer (score 1):

I know it didn't work for you, but I am using  `mymodule_comment_view_alter()` (i.e. hooking into hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter) to selectively hide **individual comments**.

Although $build didn't have an '#access' key, eventually I tried

```
$build['#access'] = false;
```

and that *does* work, for comments anyway.

Also I don't need to clear the cache at all whilst editing the hook (I do have Twig debugging on it local.services.yml, but with twig.config.cache still enabled.)

(Drupal 8.5.5)

Comment: Unfortunately this question is specifically about **paragraph** entities, not comments. The bit about 'any other entity really' is in reference to other ways of achieving this :)